# Overloaded operator doesn't get detected

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

A little back ground first, I've made a doubly linked list using templates. I have an "account" class in which I've overloaded the "==" operator to compare the account ID's. I've created a linked list to hold the accounts.

When I add a new account to the list, it calls the "contains?" method which calls the == operator. This is where the error is invoked and g++ tells me

> sll.h: In member function ‘bool list::contains(T) [with T = account]’:
>
> customer.h:25:35:   instantiated from here
>
> sll.h:261:3: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘temp->node::data == item’
>
> account.h:36:6: note: candidate is: bool account::operator==(account&)

I've been investigating for a few hours now and I can't get to the bottom of it. I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that I"m using templates. I created test program to see if I'm overloading the operator correctly and it works as expected.

Also note: there is a customer class which is what the accounts list in contained in and this is what's called "add" method. Unfortunately I can't post more than 2 hyperlinks so just take my word for it that this class is properly made. =P

As the code is somewhat long I used pastie:

[Linked list class](http://pastie.org/2050806)

[Account class](http://pastie.org/2050812)

Answer (score 6):

Your operator== takes its right argument as non const reference while you are trying to compare with a const parameter.  BTW, your operator== is also a non const member.

1. Your operator== should be a const member and take a const reference paramter
2. Your operator== would be better to be a free function or the two parameters won't be handled in the same way for conversion and you have an implicit conversion from string to account.
3. Is that implicit conversion really wanted?
4. You have public data member is account.  Is it really wanted?